# Using non-default PYTHONPATH for pylsp installation in neovim

Tags: neovim, neovim-plugin

I'm trying to add python-lsp-server in my neovim enviroment.
For my project I need to use non-default (not `/usr/bin/python3`) python3 version.

How can I use my own python3 version?

I'm try to run `PYTHONPATH=/usr/lib/<PATH_TO_PYTHON3.7> nvim`.
But when I use `:LspInstall pylsp' command after that, in log I see, that python3.5(old) python version were used.

Comment: could you elaborate why do you care about which version of python that pylsp is using?

Comment: I'm using ubuntu 16.04 with default python3.5, but pylsp works only with python3>=3.6

Answer (score 0):

Solved using vim.g.python3_host_prog variable in init.lua:

```
vim.g.python3_host_prog = 'usr/bin/python3.7'
```